# Interaction between slave and master when incremental index update is done in master in SOLR

Tags: solr

When I update a few docs in solr master, there would be one more segment in the index. As the slave polls and replicates, does it only copy the new segment or the entire index anyway? I would image it would only copy the new segment but I am not very clear whether that's the case.

I do see the slave has the same number of segments as the master but I am getting GC spike even for a few docs update in slave side. I am using SOLR 4.1 by the way. Another related questions is whether a searcher is per index or per segment? I would guess it is per index but just want to confirm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the new segments should be replicated, but Solr 4.1 had a known bug, when the whole index was replicated. We experienced the same trouble and upgrading to 4.2.1 and to 4.3.1 resolved this issue.

See a discussion of this bug [here](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Slaves-always-replicate-entire-index-amp-Index-versions-td4041256.html).

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other known issues around replication in Solr 4.1 in full refresh (as opposed to incremental update)?

Comment: Yes, there were many bugs. You can see [SOLR-4471](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4471), for example: replication was done even if it was not required.